# React checkbox update after second click

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, use-state, setstate

**I am trying to implement multiple checkboxes but onChange takes effect only after another click on other checkboxes here is the code snippet :**

here I Initialize the array of objects that's going to get rendered as checkboxes on component render

```
const contentFilters = ['Videos', 'Life Events', 'Collabs'];
const [selectedContentFilters, setSelectedContentFilter] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      setSelectedContentFilter(
      contentFilters.map((filter, index) => {
        return {
          id: index + 1,
          label: filter,
          checked: false,
        };
      }),
    );
  }, []);
```

here is how I map the array of objects into checkboxes components

```
{selectedContentFilters.map((filter) => {
                    return (
                      <DropDownItem key={filter.id}>
                        <CheckboxContainer>
                          <input
                            id={filter.id}
                            type={'checkbox'}
                            onChange={() => {
                              _setSelectedContentFilter(filter.id);
                            }}
                            checked={filter.checked}
                            name={filter.label}
                          />
                          <Label>{filter.label}</Label>
                        </CheckboxContainer>
                      </DropDownItem>
                    );
                  })}
```

here is the _selectedContentFilter that gets called once the onChange triggers to update the array state, I Clone the array in order to dont have the same reference and cause the re-render on state update :

```
const _setSelectedContentFilter = (id) => {
    let cloneSelectedContentFilter = [...selectedContentFilters];
    cloneSelectedContentFilter = cloneSelectedContentFilter.map((filter) => {
      if (filter.id === id) {
        filter.checked = !filter.checked;
      }
      return filter;
    });
    setSelectedContentFilter(cloneSelectedContentFilter);
  };
```

Comment: The code works fine when omit `DropDownItem` and `CheckboxContainer`: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-fermat-wnypj9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @user4980215 thank you! react-bootstrap dropdown item component was causing the strange result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused from the react-bootstrap dropdown item component that cause the checkboxes to delay the re-render .